# Wrong odata.context type in response of teams/{team-id}/members/add

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

after a successfull POST request to the graph api to add team members, the returned odata.context type is "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#Collection(microsoft.graph.actionResultPart)".

Shouldn't it be of the type "microsoft.graph.aadUserConversationMemberResult" like it is described in the examples: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/conversationmembers-add?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http

POST to url "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/teams/{team-id}/members/add"

The body of the request is

```
{
  "values": [
    {
      "user@odata.bind": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users('7a6ae53d-1e05-4265-ac85-997967fcc9fd')",
      "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.aadUserConversationMember",
      "roles": [
        "owner"
      ]
    },
    {
      "user@odata.bind": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users('092a3420-60b4-4232-aa21-655da31871a0')",
      "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.aadUserConversationMember",
      "roles": [
        "owner"
      ]
    }
  ],
  "id": "c97869d1-a721-4202-80bd-505b801b0996"
}
```

response

```
{
  "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#Collection(microsoft.graph.actionResultPart)",
  "@odata.count": 2,
  "value": [
    {
      "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.aadUserConversationMemberResult",
      "userId": "092a3420-60b4-4232-aa21-655da31871a0",
      "error": null
    },
    {
      "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.aadUserConversationMemberResult",
      "userId": "7a6ae53d-1e05-4265-ac85-997967fcc9fd",
      "error": null
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Yes, it should be https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#Collection(microsoft.graph.aadUserConversationMemberResult). Is it important for you?

Comment: I wanted it to use to parse the response into objects, I also can use the odata type of each json object... thanks